# Angular 4 SCSS not updating component

Tags: angular, mean-stack

I am new to Angular 4. I am building a MEAN app with Angular 4. My style.scss file(in the root folder) is able to update the nav components. However, the home.component.scss (in the home folder) is not updating the home component. I am not sure where to look. Thanks for your kind support!

Comment: sorted it out never mind thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your component decorator have property styleUrls linked to your scss like so:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss'], <--- this
  template: ``
})
```